# jquery.blockUI plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-blockui

I have a simple div that I want to disable:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
</div>
```

I perform below:

```
$('#MyDiv').blockUI({
    message: '<h1>This has been blocked!</h1>',
    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
});
```

In runtime an error is thrown:

"Object does not support/accept this property or method 'blockUI'"

I have included it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/jquery.blockUI.js")"></script>
```

and I use jquery.blockUI version Version 2.66.0-2013.10.09 which is compatible with the version of jquery I am using jquery-1.10.2 and jquery-ui.1.10.3

Any ideas what is it failing?

Comment: `console.log($.blockUI)` shows what?

Comment: @farmer1992 I have put console.log($.blockUI) as you have stated in the line just before using blockUI and the result is: undefined

Comment: obviously, your blockui.js did not load. check it from dev panel.

Comment: In visual studio it appears as loaded and from internet explorer dev tools, in network tab, as well...

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something like this , you are calling blockUI like this `$('#MyDiv').blockUI` but see the documentation thats not the correct way of calling

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo3').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({
    message: '<h1>This has been blocked!</h1>',
    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
});
    }); 
}); 
</script>
<body>
<div id=MyDiv"></div>
<div id="demo3">fff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24y7L/)

Comment: Well, taking into account the example here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions I am not agree. As I understand then you cannot block a div or any other object if you do not provoke an event previously... If I want to block an object without provoking any event on it, why I cannot do this? I think it is not the goal of jquery blockUI. I should be able to block any object depending on some conditions whenever I want.

Comment: Here it applies on the object itself: $('div.test').block({ message: null });  this example has been extracted from the link indicated in the previous comment.

Comment: yeah if you want to block a specific div or tag or something you ca use  $('#id').block({ message: null });   http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Comment: I just added a sample for entire page blocking , thats it. :)